# Ref doesn't get updated when state change and ref is set to another div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I set the opacity of element in someFunc, it doesn't set last element's opacity but one before. Ref is not updated instantly.

Elements' opacity will stay "1" in normal. This opacity change is needed just for the last added element and for short time.

How can I access the last element of that div in the same line of someFunc ?

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [divisions, setDivisions] = useState([]);
  const itemRef = useRef();

  const someFunc = () => {
    const newDivision = {
      id: "someId",
      someData: "someText"
    }
    setDivisions(prevState => [...prevState, newDivision])
    itemRef.current.style.opacity = "0.7"
  }

  return ( 
   <>
    <div onClick={someFunc}>Button</div>
    <div className="container">
    {divisions.map((item, key) => {
        return <div id={item.id} ref={itemRef}>item.someData</div>
      })
    }
    </div>
   </>
 )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Shouldn't you have an array of itemRef just like you have an array of division objects? Your code now is assigning one itemRef to an array of divs

Comment: Thanks for welcoming! But I want just one ref object, just for the last element added to state.

Comment: If all you want to do is set the opacity of the last element inside container, wouldn't it be easier to use CSS instead of a useRef?

Comment: I want it to be dynamic. In my scenario, every div contains data. When data which div contains is loaded completely to database, I want to change the opacity of div.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using the same ref on the mapped elements. simply change your div to the below

```
<div id={item.id} ref={(el) => (itemRef.current[key] = el)}>item.someData</div>
```

and your function to this

```
const someFunc = () => {
    const newDivision = {
      id: "someId",
      someData: "someText"
    }
    setDivisions(prevState => [...prevState, newDivision])
    for (let i = 0; i < itemRef.current.length; i++) {
       if(i ===  (itemRef.current.length - 1))
       {
       itemRef.current[i].style.opacity = "0.7"
       }
    }
  }
```

then inform react by calling useEffect

```
useEffect((console.log(itemRef)) => {},[itemRef])
```

Comment: I think this will change all element's opacity to "0.7". Their opacity will stay "1" in normal. This opacity change just for the last added element and for short time.

Comment: @Ismailkaraağaç apologies, updated to set only last element opacity

Comment: ah, I forgot to add container for divs in question. In your answer, your itemRef is for parent, right? That makes sense, I'll try it

Comment: It didn't work. It changes the opacity of element one before last element

Comment: @Ismailkaraağaç you need to add useEffect to inform react of the change, check updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add the `ref` to the last item by counting `divisions` (minus one as you're matching to the key which starts at zero - I added brackets ( ... ) for clarity but they're optional):

```
ref={key === (divisions.length - 1) && itemRef}
```

Comment: It gives me this error  => Error: Function components cannot have string refs.

Comment: Try `ref={key === (divisions.length - 1) ? itemRef : undefined}`